# Is there a fully qualified DNS hostname for DNS over TLS (DoT) for Cloudflare Family?

Tags: dns, tls, cloudflare, dot

In my router, I want to enable DNS over TLS for my DNS requests. I want to use [cloudflare's server](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-1-1-1-1-for-families), namely the family one blocking malware.

```
Malware Blocking Only

Primary DNS: 1.1.1.2
Secondary DNS: 1.0.0.2

Primary DNS: 2606:4700:4700::1112
Secondary DNS: 2606:4700:4700::1002
```

I can add these DNS servers just fine in my DNS settings. Yet when I want to furthermore enable DNS over TLS, I have to provide a fully qualified DNS server.

Searching for the config, it says to add:

https://one.one.one.one/

yet this appears to the DNS server without malware protection.

Is there no https://one.one.one.two/ for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [forum entry](https://www.snbforums.com/threads/cloudflare-dns-over-tls-malware-settings.77655/post-748224):

> Use `1.1.1.2` and `1.0.0.2` with `security.cloudflare-dns.com`
>
> `1.1.1.3` and `1.0.0.3` uses `family.cloudflare-dns.com`

The first one is malware only, the second blocks malware and adult content.